# Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, dlib

```
  CMake Error at C:/Users/Woojin/AppData/Local/Temp/pip-install-v6txp2ap/dlib/dlib/external/pybind11/tools/FindPythonLibsNew.cmake:124 (message):
    Python config failure: Python is 32-bit, chosen compiler is 64-bit
```

I got the above error.
Please tell me how to solve this problem.